# Can't connect to MySQL database over local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mac, mysql

I have two macbooks at my home connected via Wi-Fi to my router. One of them has a MySQL server installed. I want to access a MySQL DB from the second mac. I found the internal IP address of the first mac and tried to use `mysql -u <user> -p -h <internal IP>` and I get

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<internal IP>:3306'
```

To test the issue I pinged the internal IP of the first mac from the second mac and it worked.
When I try `telnet <internal IP> 3306` from the second mac, I get

```
Trying <internal IP>...
telnet: connect to address <internal IP>: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Just to make sure that I got the port correct, I try `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` on the first mac and it works.
So this is probably some network configuration issue.
I tried setting bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in the my.cnf file but it didn't help.

Does anyone has an idea?
thanks

Comment: Could you please post the output of `netstat -tulpn` when run on the machine where MySQL is running?

Comment: MySQL typically doesn’t allow remote connections only the local machine, so have you modified the configuration, to allow remote connections within your local network?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. The solution is to create a new MySQL user with the relevant privileges like so

```
create user '<user>'@'192.168.1.%' identified by '<password>';
grant all privileges on *.* to '<user>'@'192.168.1.%' with grant option;
```

And to change `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in the my.cnf file (for me its path is /usr/local/etc/my.cnf). And then it works!

Comment: Can I pls ask what does *.* and grant option means?